# Find all lines on cubic surface

Tags: geometry, algebraic-geometry

**Problem:** Find the singular point of the cubic surface

$$ZX^2 - Y^3 + TZ^2 = 0.$$

And also determine all the lines on the surface.

**My attempt:** I calculated the singular point by setting the partial derivatives to $0$ and I got $P = (0 : a : 0 : b)$ where $a, b$ are not both zero. **Did I get this right?**

About calculating the lines, I have no idea where to start. Is there perhaps some sort of technique/method/proposition for doing this? Can someone perhaps show me as an answer how to do this for this problem since I have two more of this type to do and then I can practice on those other two.

As a side question: Is there perhaps some criterion of determining the amount of total lines on the surface?

Note: We are in $\mathbb{P}^{3}$ over an algebraically closed field which does not have characteristic $2$.

Comment: $Y=Z=0$ is one line, call it $L$. You can find the others by taking the pencil of planes through $L$ (this is a $1$-dimensional family parametrized by some parameter $\lambda$): the so-called residual intersection of each plane with the cubic surface is a conic $C_\lambda$ (since the total intersection has degree $3$, but $L$ is a component of it). It is not hard (but probably slightly tedious) to find an equation for $C_\lambda$, and so find all $\lambda$ such that $C_\lambda$ degenerates into two lines: generically there are five such $\lambda$s, so you will need to solve a quintic equation.

Comment: Then for each of the (at most) $10$ new lines found in this way, you repeat the procedure. I think this will get you all the other lines, but you will have to look up the intersection pattern of lines on a cubic surface to be sure about this. (I think Schläffli sixfolds come in useful here.)

Comment: @RP_ Thanks. So far most of the terms you talk about are unfamiliar to me. I will look them up at try to solve it. Will work on it this weekend and come back with the progress and see if I get stuck somewhere.

Comment: Where I said 'conic' I should have said 'conic section'. That is a plane curve of degree 2. Forget the part about Schläffli sixfolds, I seem to recall that for every pair $L,L'$ of lines on a cubic surface, there is always a third line intersecting them both. So if you repeat the procedure a total of two times, you will get all lines. Good luck!

Comment: @RP_ Is the pencil given by $A_1 X + B_1 Y + C_1 Z - D_1 + \lambda (A_2 X + B_2 Y + C_2 Z - D_2)$ and by using our line with $Y = Z = 0$ we get $A_1 X - D_1 + \lambda (A_2 X - D_2) = 0$?

Comment: No, if a line is defined by $F=G=0$, then the pencil is given by $F+\lambda G=0$. This equation defines a plane for each $\lambda$, and they all have the line $F=G=0$ in common (as you can check). So in this case the pencil is given by $Y+\lambda Z=0$. To find the conic sections $C_\lambda$, you intersect the planes with the original cubic surface.

Comment: @RP:"You can find the others by taking the pencil of planes through L " Really? What makes you think that the other lines would be contained in a plane passing through $L$?

Comment: @RP: You should do yourself the trivial calculations you suggest and you will notice that the residual conic $C_\lambda$   **never** degenerates into two lines. I have no idea what quintic equation you are talking about.

Comment: No, saudimau, your calculation is not correct: the only singularity of your cubic surface is $(0:0:0:1)$, whereas your description yields infinitely many points. By the way, where does that question come from? The difficulty of computing the lines on the surface is several orders of magnitudes greater than that of finding its singular points, so that something is a  bit strange in your two questions. – Georges Elencwajg 37 mins ago

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg It's a homework question given that we have to practice on the theory we learned. The problem is that we never did an example calculation of lines in class. We only stated facts like for instance that a non-singular cubic surface has 27 lines.

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg My apologies, I assumed that there would be other lines on the surface besides this particular one. My strategy works fine for smooth cubic surfaces, but I had no idea that there were cubic surfaces containing just a single line.

Comment: That's quite all right, dear @RP_:thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a) It is quite easy to see that the only singularity of the projective surface $S\subset \mathbb P^3$ given by the equation $ZX^2 - Y^3 + TZ^2 = 0$ is the point $$P=[x:y:z:t]=[0:0:0:1]\in S$$
That type of singularity is called $E_6$ by the specialists.
b) It is also quite clear that the line $L$ given by the two equations $Y=Z=0$ lies on $S$ (i.e. $L\subset S$).
c) What is true **but not clear at all** however is that $L$ is the *only* line of $\mathbb P^3$ lying on $S$.
I know no elementary proof of that fact, which follows from the rather complicated classification of  singular cubic surfaces in projective $3$-space.

**Reference**
Bruce-Wall's article [*On the Classification of Cubic Surfaces*](https://doi.org/10.1112/jlms/s2-19.2.245), Lemma 4, page 251  and second table, page 255.
(Beware that their paper is written in a rather old-fashioned  style.)

Comment: Let me perhaps explains what we covered: Every cubic surface in $\mathbb{P}^{3}$ contains at least one line. Then some propositions for non-singular cubic surfaces which do not apply since we have a singularity. And the explanation for finding more lines was heuristically given in the notes like: Take an irreducible cubic surface, then it contains at least one line $L$. To find more lines we study the $1$-dimensional linear system of planes (pencil) through the line $L$. Each plane $\Pi$ through $L$ intersects the surface in a reducible cubic plane curve consisting of $L$ and a residual conic.

Comment: The problem with the heuristic explanation is that I don't know what a pencil is i.e. have no computational methods to study it. Second, what does studying the pencil mean? Then when studying each plane $\Pi$ through $L$ it intersects the surface in a reducible plane curve consisting of $L$ and a residual conic. So how does this help me find more lines? And what is a residual conic?

Comment: Dear saudimau, you have all my sympathy! Your course is very badly structured. If you are a beginner in this area the"hints" you were given are foolish, since they use techniques you have not been taught yet. What is worse: the teacher seems incompetent since there is no reason why any further line on the cubic should be on a plane passing through the first line: two lines on a cubic surface are often skew to each other, i.e. are not contained in a common plane. As I already wrote, the problem is quite difficult and it is really irresponsible to assign it as an exercise to a beginner!

Comment: Dear Georges Elencwajg, thanks for the clarification and your sympathy! You once answered the following question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2268545/intersection-of-a-hypersurface-v-subset-mathbbpn-with-a-tangent-hyperplan/2269076 I have an analogous question to solve only that my hypersurface is from affine space rather than projective space. Will the same idea go through? I would have commented on that post, but I do not have enough reputation to comment.

Answer (score 2):

Let me give a computational answer. The idea is to form the general line

$$x = p_1 + l q_1, \quad y = p_2 + l q_2, \quad z = p_3 + l q_3, \quad
t = p_4 + l q_4$$

Substitute that into the cubic $f(x,y,z,t) = z x^2 - y^3 + t z^2$, and collect coefficients $a_i$ of $l$. Form an Ideal $I$ from these coefficients $a_i$.

It is an ideal in $\mathbb{Q}[p_i,q_j]$.

Now consider the 6 Plücker coordinates

$$\xi_i : w_i - \psi_i(p_k,q_l)$$

where the $\psi_i$ are the six $2$-minors of

$$\begin{pmatrix} p_1 & p_2 & p_3 & p_4 \\ q_1 & q_2 & q_3 & q_4 \end{pmatrix}$$

Form a ring $T=\mathbb{Q}[p_i, q_j, w_l]$ and take the ideal $J = I + (\xi_i)_i$ of $T$. Eliminate from this ideal the variables $p_i,q_j$, it remains an Ideal $L$ of $T_1=\mathbb{Q}[w_1,\ldots,w_6]$. The zeros of this ideal $L$ are the points in Plücker space corresponding to the lines on $V(f)$. Now to see that only one line exist, do a generic linear projection from

$$\mathbf{P}^5 = \mathrm{proj}( T_1) \to \mathbf{P}^1 = \mathrm{proj} (\mathbb{Q}[u_1,u_2])$$

Compute the ideal of the image by elimination and find out, that it is

$$(a u_1 + b u_2)^{17}$$

with $a,b \in \mathbb{Z}$ depending on the projection choosen. Why $17$ and not $27$? (I don't know).

On Macaulay2 homepage

https://faculty.math.illinois.edu/Macaulay2/

you find a web interface of Macaulay 2 on which you can run the code below (computation time is short):

https://www.unimelb-macaulay2.cloud.edu.au/#home

(You can copy the code below with Control-C and insert it with Control-V on line i1 in the web interface.)

```
-- We need all these variables for our computation

R = QQ[p_1..p_4,q_1..q_4,l,x,y,z,t]


-- our singular cubic

f = z * x^2 - y^3 + t * z^2

-- as a test a nonsingular cubic
-- f = x^3 + y^3 + z^3 + t^3

-- the variables of the projective Space P^3

vs = {x,y,z,t}

-- we make a substitute list x => p_1 + l * q_1, y => p_2 + l * q_2, and so on

sl = toList apply(1..4, i-> vs_(i-1) => p_i + l * q_i)

-- we apply these substitute list on f getting a polynomial in p_1..q_4 and l
-- we want that it vanishes exactly in l, so we take coefficients with respect to l

cfs = coefficients(sub(f, sl), Variables=>{l})

-- we form the ideal of these coefficients, it is an ideal of QQ[p_1..p_4,q_1..q_4]

iJ = ideal cfs_1

-- we provide explicitly the ring S with only p_i, q_i as variables

S = QQ[p_1..q_4]

-- now we prepare the canonical map from R to S which is identity on p_i, q_j and 0 otherwise

psi=map(S,R)

-- now we transfer our ideal in this smaller ring

iJ1 = psi(iJ)

-- we switch the default input to ring S

use S

-- we prepare to map the solutions of iJ to Plücker-coordinates

mM = matrix {{p_1,p_2,p_3,p_4},{q_1,q_2,q_3,q_4}}

-- the 6 polynomials in iK are the expressions of the Plücker variables

iK = minors(2, mM)

-- w_1..w_6 are our Plücker-coordinates, T has p_i, q_j, w_s as coordinates

T = S[w_1..w_6]

gamma = map(T,S)

-- we form the ideal w_a = psi_a(p_i, q_j) where psi_a are the Plücker expressions

iK1 = ideal toList(apply(1..6, i->w_i - gamma(iK_(i-1))))

-- our goal is to eliminate the p_i, q_j from the ideal made of iJ and iK1
-- we call this ideal iK2

iK2 = iK1 + gamma(iJ1)

-- following line can be ignored
elv = apply({p_1,p_2,p_3,p_4,q_1,q_2,q_3,q_4}, z->gamma(z))

-- we do the elimination by kernel computation

-- T1 is our final coordinate space

T1 = QQ[w_1..w_6]

-- the following two lines do elimination of p_i, q_j by a kernel computation.

rho=map(T/iK2, T1)

-- iL is our solution ideal in Plücker coordinates. It is of dim = 1 (projective dim = 0)
-- and degree 27

iL = ker rho

-- just to get a bit better informed, we calculate the primaryDecomposition of iL

pd1 = primaryDecomposition iL

iL1 = pd1_0

-- we want to project V(iL) to a line with a random linear projection

uw1 = sum toList(apply(1..6, i->random(-20,20) * w_i))

uw2 = sum toList(apply(1..6, i->random(-20,20) * w_i))

-- our ring that corresponds to a projective line

T2 = QQ[u_1,u_2]

-- here we do the projection by elimination

rho1 = map(T1/iL, T2, {uw1,uw2})

-- iL2 contains only one element g

iL2 = ker rho1

g = iL2_0

-- see for yourself, that g1 = l^17 with l linear in u_1,u_2
-- why 17 and not 27: I do not know, perhaps a question for Georges Elencwajg

g1 = factor g
```

Comment: @Georges Elencwajg Do you know a mathematical reason why $17$ appears here and not $27$? (The ideal iL has degree $27$ and consists of a primary component of degree $27$ and dimension $1$ and a primary component of dimension $0$ and degree $31$)

Comment: `R = QQ[x,y,z,t]`
`f = ideal(z*x^2 - y^3 + t*z^2)`
`iF = Fano(1,f);`
`degree iF -- 27`
`L=primaryDecomposition iF;`
`radical L_0 -- ideal(p_5,p_4,p_2,p_1,p_0)`
`degree L_0 -- 27`

Comment: Dear Jürgen, first of all congratulations and thank you for this computation which confirms the Bruce-Wall result  :+1. And, no,  I have no idea where the exponent 17 comes from. This again shows  how ridiculous it was to give this question as an exercise, especially to a beginner in algebraic geometry like our new friend saudimau. Übrigens, würden Sie mir meine Neugierde verzeihen, wenn ich Sie nach Ihrer Herkunft frage? Ich meinerseits bin, trotz meines Namens, Franzose .

Comment: @Georges Elencwajg Ich bin Deutscher, wie auch die Umlaute schon andeuten - geboren in Friesland (Norddeutschland), meine Eltern kommen aus Franken und dem Sudetenland. Sie selbst waren ja lange an der Universität Brüssel, wenn ich mich recht entsinne - ich habe Ihre Beiträge hier oft gelesen. (Meine Homepage ist www.aviduratas.de (oder www.juergenboehm.net))

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I will look at it tomorrow. BTW I am (perhaps) allowed to use Macaulay2 will ask the teacher via email; however, we only got a basic intro to it. Übringens, ich spreche auch Deutsch.

Comment: And you got 17 instead of 27. When I followed the method given here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1209963/lines-on-a-singular-cubic-surface I got 27 as an output from Macaulay2.

Comment: Lieber Jürgen: vielen Dank für Ihre schnelle Antwort. Ich bin tatsächlich im französichsprachigen Teil Belgiens aufgewachsen, aber ganz erstaunt, dass Sie sich meines Studiums in Brüssel entsinnen. Ich erinnere mich in der Tat nicht, dies je auf dieser Site erwähnt zu haben. Im übrigen, hier kommt der Clou: ich habe Ihr Buch "Kommutative Algebra und Algebraische Geometrie"  voriges Jahr gekauft und war begeistert  wie reich und präzise es ist. Ich komme mir jetzt ganz dumm vor, Sie nicht als den Autor erkannt zu haben! Wie dem auch sei: gratuliere zum vortrefflichen Werk!

Comment: @saudimau I think I know the reason for 17 vs 27: In the process of projection of the fat point in $\mathbf{P}^5$ some normal material lies in the projecting hyperplane and so gets lost. (The projection $X=\mathbf{P}^5 \to \mathbf{P}^1=Y$ is characterized by a line $Y$ in $X$ and a $3$-plane $W \subseteq X$. A point $Q \in X$ is projected to $Y$ by forming the joint hyperplane $H(Q)$ of $W$ and $Q$ and intersecting it with $Y$. Normal material of a fat point $Q$ that lies in $H(Q)$ gets projected away).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a direct way of showing the cubic surface $S=\{ZX^2-Y^3+Z^2T=0\}$ with an $E_6$-sigularity contains a single line.

Suppose there is another line $L$ in $S$ and is different from the line $\{Y=Z=0\}$ through the singularity, then $L$ must contain a point $p$ of the form $$p=(x_0,y_0,1,t_0),$$

and $L$ lies in the tangent hyperplane $T_pS$. The condition $p\in S$ requires that $t_0=y_0^3-x_0^2$, so $T_pS$ has equation

$$2x_0X-3y_0^2Y+(2y_0^3-x_0^2)Z+T=0.$$

The intersection $C=T_pS\cap S$ is a cubic plane curve and $C$ contains $L$ as an irreducible component, therefore $C$ is reducible. However, by isolating $T$ in the linear equation and cancelling $T$ in the cubic surface equation, one finds the equation of $C$ is
$$ZX^2-Y^3-Z^2[2x_0X-3y_0^2Y+(2y_0^3-x_0^2)Z]$$

in the projective plane with coordinate $X,Y,Z$. Of course, $C$ is singular at $p=(x_0,y_0,1)$ since it is tangency point. However, a direct computation of partial derivatives shows that $p$ is the only singularity of $C$ and it is an ordinary double point if $y_0\neq 0$, is an ordinary cusp if $y_0=0$. Therefore $C$ is irreducible, which is a contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

From the fact that the Fano scheme $F_1(S)$ of normal cubic surface that is not a cone is finite of degree $27$, this fact is not hard to check by hand. Consider the affine open subscheme of $G(2, 4)$ consiting planes not meeting $V(x, w)$, with coordinates
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & a & c & 0 \\
0 & b & d & 1 \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$

the Fano scheme in this chart is given by zero locus of coefficients of polynomial
$$
t^2(ct + du) + (at + du)^3 + (ct + du)^2u
$$
so it is cut out by ideal in $\mathbb A^4$
$$
I = (c-a^2, d-3a^2b+c^2, 2cd - 3ab^2, d^2-b^3) 
$$
it is easy to see that the algebra $S/I$ is finite of dimension $27$, generated as vector space by $27$ monomials in $a, b$ not divisible by $a^9$ and $b^3$. Thus since $F_1(S)$ contains a point of degree $27$, this must be its only component.

Obviously this relies of the fact that ideed $F_1(S)$ has degree $27$ for all cubics. There are a few different approaches to this problem. One can show for example that this is true for smooth cubics and that the projection from the family of Fano schemes over cubics from the open subset of $\mathbb P(H^0(\mathcal O(3))$ parameterising cubics with finitely many line is flat (as in *Geometry of schemes* by Eisenbud and Harris) or realising the cycle of $F_1(X)$ as as the $4$th Chern class of $\operatorname{Sym}^3(\mathcal S^\vee)$ (as in *3264 & All That Intersection Theory in Algebraic Geometry*, also by Eisenbud and Harris)